# Erro ao tentar importar banco de dados no phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, wordpress, phpmyadmin

Estou migrando um site wordpress de um servidor para outro. Criei um novo banco de dados MySQL no novo servidor, porém ao clicar em "importar" recebo essa mensagem.

[image: phpmyadmin]

Como resolver?